# QtCreator: how to see program output when deployed on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm using QtCreator to design and deploy Android applications.

When debugging the application, when I invoke some Java SDK code, if this one calls `System.out.println`, I see the message in QtCreator console.

Now, from C++/Qt code, I could not find out how to show a message in QtCreator console.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171653/can-i-see-the-program-output-in-qt-creator) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299981/how-can-i-see-qdebug-messages-while-debugging-in-qtcreator), I tried:

```
qDebug() << "Hello there";
qDebug( "Hello you" );
std::cout << "Hi guy" << std::endl;
std::cerr << "Hi guy 2" << std::endl;
```

With and without `CONFIG += console` being set, none of the messages above are visible in QtCreator console ('Application output').

Does anyone know how where a message has to be sent in order to have it be visible in QtCreator console while debugging an Android application?

Edit 22/05/2015: Created bug report https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-14498

Comment: Did you try to used `adb logcat`?

Comment: No, I'd like something integrated in QtCreator IDE

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moved to Qt 5.5.0 with QtCreator 3.5.0: problem solved.